# interactiveGestureRecognizer and panGestureRecognizer together

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have problem. I want realize slide menu, but want keep swipe to back gesture. I add panGestureRecognizer to my View and I get undefined behavior in working app. When I swipe from edge, triggered then one or the other gesture. How can I control it or what I doing wrong?

Comment: You should make a single gesture for both swipes. And detect which one you want to use in the function that you trigger of that gesture.

Comment: Can you give example, please? I don't understand how can I influence on interactiveGestureRecognizer or simulate it behavior

Comment: I cannot say, since your question is too little detailed. Provide me with a piece of relevant code of what you have done.

Comment: I only did it in my ViewController `code`- (void) viewDidLoad {
   ...
   UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                           action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
   panRecognizer.delegate = self;
   [_view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}`code`. This gesture can triggered when i swipe from gesture.

Comment: And what about the interactiveGestureRecognizer?

Comment: interactiveGestureRecognizer is enabled

Comment: And what and when does that trigger? (I'm lacking a hell of a load of information here) You probably have to either disable this interactiveGestureRecognizer and do all the handling yourself with normal UIGestureRecognizers. Or you should make the interactiveGestureRecognizer work for all different gestures.

Comment: You can try to use this `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and disable you panGesture when the InteractiveGestureRecognizer start.